# Airy-like equation with non-linear term

Tags: numerical-methods, airy-functions

I am trying to solve numerically the following equation $$y'' = xy + y^3$$ I know that for $x<0$ it can be approximately described by $y = \sqrt{-x}$. So I tried to solve it in MATLAB and mathematica with initial conditions $y(-5) = \sqrt{5},~y'(-5) = -1/(2\sqrt{5})$ but both programs failed to solve it properly. After certain iteration the step size became smaller than solver limit. Any suggestions how it can be solved?

Comment: To use standard ODE solvers (in Python,MatLab,...) you need to reduce the system to a first order one. Did you do that? @anatoly

Comment: If you mean split it like g(x) = y'(x), g'(x) = xy + y^3, than I did it.

Comment: Okay, so it's likely that the solution is a bit steep in some region. Which odesolver did you try to use? Have you tried to use stiff ode solvers, like ode23tb, ode15s? (see mathworks website for some examples)

Comment: Yes, I tried stiff and non stiff. Well actually I found that this problem is more complicated than I thought, however I found a paper which describes some methods for resolving this problem https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.2123.pdf